# GWT : Generate THEAD in TABLE

Tags: java, html, gwt

Is that possible to generate THEAD in a TABLE in GWT ? Do I have to create my own Widget ?

I'm following the Google Tutorial on GWT, https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted... but when see the generated HTML I get sick :o)

So I gess that yes I can use whatever I need to use to be able to generate better HTML.

In fact, I have to report if I can do good HTML/CSS/JS whith this technology. So I try to know what is possible to do with GWT.

Comment: _It depends._ Can you use a `CellTable`?

Comment: Yes, I can. As I'm following the tutorial I get no restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column headers of `CellTable`s will be rendered in a `<thead>` section.

You can also use HTML with an HTMLPanel (made much easier using UiBinder) if you don't need to manipulate the table's structure dynamically (assuming you're putting widgets in there, otherwise you can very well do whatever you want with it; this is because widgets have a specific lifecycle to avoid memory leaks with event handlers).